# How to avoid dummy return in try catch block while a method which throws exception is called?

Tags: java, exception

I know it is required that in a non-void method, `return` or `throw` is a must.
But I don't like the dummy return in catch block in such case:

```
public int call() throws Exception {
  try { 
    return calcMethod();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    process(e);
    return 0;
  }
}

protected void process(Exception e) throws xxxException {
  if ( isTypeAException(e) ) { throw new TypeAException() ; } 
  else if ( isTypeBException(e) ) { throw new TypeBException() ; } 
  else ( isTypeCException(e) ) { throw new TypeCException() ; } 
}

...
```

`process` will certainly throws an exception, then why `return` is still required in `catch` block?

Comment: Perhaps `process()` should rather be an exception factory. Strictly speaking, if an exception is thrown in `process()`, that should mean there was a problem with `process`ing.

Comment: Why not make process() return the exception rather than throw it? Exception should really never be the expected behaviour of a method.

Comment: Some clarification - I think the compiler error should be avoided by compiler itself as it should know if an exception will be thrown in a method, then why compiler still gives me the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one sense, throwing the exception in `process()` is to be construed as "a problem with processing", which is also not what you mean.

As you want the exception to be raised by `call()`, so the solution here is to make `process()` an exception factory:

```
public int call() throws Exception {
    try {
        return calcMethod();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw process(e);
    }
}

protected xxxException process(Exception e) throws xxxException {
    if (isTypeAException(e))
        return new TypeAException();
    else if (isTypeBException(e))
        return new TypeBException();
    else
        return new TypeCException();
}
```

Comment: This is also one workaround I found by myself, but to be honest I have never seen such practice before and I felt interesting somehow astonished when I found it works in my code.